# How do I set breakpoints and continue with the debugger?

Tags: c++, c, linux, gdb, esp32

```
GNU gdb (crosstool-NG esp-2020r3) 8.1.0.20180627-git
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=x86_64-build_pc-linux-gnu --target=xtensa-esp32s2-elf".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from build/hello_world.elf...done.
0x40090182 in esp_pm_impl_waiti () at /home/shubha/esp/esp-idf/components/hal/esp32s2/include/hal/cpu_ll.h:202
202     asm volatile ("waiti 0\n");
JTAG tap: esp32s2.cpu tap/device found: 0x120034e5 (mfg: 0x272 (Tensilica), part: 0x2003, ver: 0x1)
esp32s2: Debug controller was reset.
esp32s2: Core was reset.
esp32s2: Target halted, PC=0x4000F9B6, debug_reason=00000000
esp32s2: Core was reset.
esp32s2: Target halted, PC=0x40000400, debug_reason=00000000
Function "app main" not defined.
Make hw breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) [answered N; input not from terminal]
```

I am trying to automate a gdb session using openocd on ESP32S2. My gdb terminal looks as below:

It looks like the main() is not executed at all. I tried answering y/n but each time the core gets reset.

The command used are:

In the following folder:
/.espressif/tools/openocd-esp32//openocd-esp32

Run openocd and open application for debugging using:

bin/openocd -f share/openocd/scripts/interface/jlink.cfg -c "adapter_khz 4000" -f share/openocd/scripts/target/esp32s2.cfg

And then start gdb in project root:
xtensa-esp32s2-elf-gdb -x gdbinit build/hello_world.elf

Comment: You should also show the gdb commands/arguments you used.

Comment: We need to see both your openocd command and gdb commands. Also, `app main` is not a valid identifier. Try `app_main` instead.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hey, I have edited my questions along with the commands, Please check

Comment: @Tarmo I am not sure where the app main identifier comes from because I have used app_main() in the main.c file.

Comment: Apparently your `gdbinit` contains the commands, so you should post it as well.

Comment: Hi. Thank you @ssbssa. The underscore between app_main was missing in my gdbinit file. It works now after correcting it.